# How to return the largest entry of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a method that takes a `int` array as parameter then returns the largest entry of the array!

That's what I did, but it didn't work!

The only error is with `largest();`

```
The method largest(int[]) in the type Moon is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

What is the problem?

```
public class Moon {
    public static void main(String[] args {     
        int array1[] = {5,10,15,20,25,30};

        int max = largest();
        System.out.println("the largest number is : " + max);

    }


    static int largest( int array1[] ){

        int maxValue = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
            if (array1[i] > array1[maxValue]) maxValue = i;       
        }
        return maxValue;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are not passing your `array1` as argument to your `largest` method. Technically Compiler Error tells enough to solve these kinds of issue.

Comment: what the answers say, and you should `return array1[maxValue];` cause you save the index in maxValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Call largest by passing the array as :

   ```
   int max = largest(array1);
   ```
2. Initialize your `max` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as:

   ```
   int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   ```
3. Change your comparison as:

   ```
   if (array1[i] > maxValue )         
      maxValue = array1[i];         
   }
   ```

Comment: @user1877061 Check this answer. I already pointed the issue (point 2 and 3) regarding the max value logic.

Comment: thx alot ,, it works ... I adjust it like u did  and it works ..
like this 
    static int largest( int array1[] ){
  
   int maxValue = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      if (array1[i] > maxValue )    
          maxValue = array1[i];    
  }
  
     
  return maxValue;

Comment: @user1877061 Good to know. Please don't forget to accept the answer you like.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't actually passing in the array as an argument. Should be:

```
int max = largest(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

1. You're forgetting to pass the array in the `largest()` call.
2. `largest()` returns the *index* of the largest value, yet the caller treats it as the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Write `int max = largest(array1);`

And your function:

```
static int largest(int array1[]){

    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int el : array1)
        if (el > maxValue)
             maxValue = el;

    return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: thaks guys a lot :D 
I did like that " int max = largest(array1); "
and it works , but when I run the code it puts the answer as 5 !!
the largest number in  the array is 30 , what's wrong !!?